# Can't get shell_exec to download a file

Tags: php, bash

I have a multithreaded cli downloader for ubuntu called Aria2c.

I've been trying to get a php script to run aria2c and download a file using shell_exec, but i can't seem to get it to work. Ultimately I plan to have an input box on a page where I can enter a link and aria would download it.

Here's the code I've come up with (for now im inputting the link manually):
`<?php $dl = shell_exec('aria2c -d /home/user/ www.downloadlink.com'); ?>`

Note that the aria2c command I specified works well in the shell; and the directory I'm attempting to download to is set to '777'.

I'm baffled as to why it's not working, any ideas?

PS: I prefer to use aria rather than the alternatives because it is multithreaded and it supports cookies.

Comment: The www/apache user has permissions to run aria?  What is in $dl?

Comment: why not multi_curl? What is the output of shell command?

Comment: Do any other shell_exec commands actually succeed?

Comment: Are you running PHP from the command line as well?

Comment: @John green: Not sure but it's working now so I guess www-data does have the permission :p  
@Nemoden: I want to be able to remotely download files onto my ubuntu VPS. The shell command downloads the specified file to /home/user/  
@Nanne: Yes other commands worked  
@Alvaro: Nop it's not from the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if PHP is running in safe_mode. `shell_exec` won't work if safe_mode is on.

EDIT: aria2c was not referenced with a full path. Referencing it like this: `shell_exec('/path/to/aria2c -d /home/user/ www.downloadlink.com')` works.

Comment: I've successfully done a couple of other commands using shell_exec so that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: Hmmm..then is aria2c binary/script in your path? If not, try referencing it with a fully qualified path i.e: `shell_exec('/path/to/aria2c -d /home/user/ www.downloadlink.com');`

Comment: Oh! Awesome that's done the trick. Now that i have seen it's working I can move onto the next stage; Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll make the assumption that you are running PHP through a web server. In such case, it's very unlikely that the web server has permission to write into your user's home directory: Apache runs as daemon with the credentials of a limited user. Also, the `PATH` env variable in Apache is not necessarily the same as your user's PATH. Last but not least, you don't check the return value or the script output.

Try something like this:

```
<?php

exec('/path/to/aria2c -d /tmp www.downloadlink.com', $output, $return_var);

var_dump($output, $return_var);

?>
```

You can get the full path for aria2c with:

```
which aria2c
```

Comment: The permission isn't a problem as I set the directory to 777. Turns out the problem was that I wasn't inputting the path to aria2c

Comment: You've set your home directory to be writable by anyone? That sounds scary even for testing purposes.. :-P

Comment: haha. Only a certain directory. It's on a VPS anyway, so not that scary :)